# Show formatted unevaluated = evaluated in ipython notebook with sympy

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, sympy, mathjax

I'd like to take notes in the ipython notebook.  Is there a way to make it work so you can write math like if it was for a textbook?

```
from sympy import init_session
init_session()

expr = Integral(x,x)
print(latex(expr),'=',latex(expr.doit()))
```

Gives for a result

```
\int x\, dx = \frac{x^{2}}{2}
```

But I'd like to see in the notebook

[image]

It works fine if I write each part in separate cells, but the output is over several lines.  I'm using Anaconda on Windows XP so it's just mathjax doing the rendering.

I'd like a function that does this and maybe even adds eqn numbering like Maple.

edit: I've just discovered HTML, this formats nicely in the notebook.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
expr = Integral(x,x)
s = latex(expr) + ' = ' + latex(expr.doit())
HTML('$(1)~~'+ s + '$' + '\n' + '$$(2)~~'+ s + '$$')
```

I guess now I need to know the best way to do automatic numbering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
In [15]: expr = Integral(x,x)

In [16]: Eq(expr, expr.doit())
Out[16]: 
          2
⌠        x 
⎮ x dx = ──
⌡        2
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for simple equations.  I read about that but figured it would output `true`.  It seems limited in what I can write.

Comment: Why would you use `HTML` if this works as expected? Can you show me an example where this would fail?

Comment: It's my first day with python so I have no idea when it wouldn't work.  What about if I want to write `x e R` (x element of Reals) at the end?  I just think something like print() that takes an array of expressions would be more useful.  Not to mention numbering somehow.

Comment: Got that. Sure! In that can you can use that.

Comment: `init_session()` does that and more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75033/discussion-between-sudhanshu-mishra-and-brian).

Answer (score 0):

So I start my notebook like this.

```
from sympy import init_session
init_session()
from IPython.display import HTML
eqn = 0
eqns = [0] * 100 # max num of eqns 
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, math
%matplotlib inline

def outs(expr, *args):
    global eqn, eqns
    eqn +=1
    eqns[eqn] = expr
    s = latex(expr)+'='+latex(expr.doit())
    for count, thing in enumerate(args):
        s += '~' + latex(thing)
    display(HTML('$$('+str(eqn)+')~~' + s +'$$'))
```

Then I can do this

```
eqn = 0
outs(Integral(x,x))
outs(Integral(x**2, x))
outs(eqns[1] + eqns[2], ', @x = 2 \Rightarrow ', (eqns[1]+eqns[2]).doit().subs(x,2))
```

And I get

[image]

Not a very elegant numbering scheme, but it's easy to reset just doing `eqn = 0`